# Linking Post Title to Specific Page ID

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've created a form to update my websites homepage with content but I wanted to know how I could set it up so that a posts title links to a specific post ID. I'd also like to add a Read More link that directs anybody reading the blog to the correct post.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Blog Name</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') ;
mysql_select_db ('tmlblog');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM php_blog ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entries from table php_blog.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $date = date("l F d Y", $row['timestamp']);

    $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $entry = stripslashes($row['entry']);
    $password = $row['password'];
    $id = $row['id'];

    if ($password == 1) {
        echo "<p><strong>" . $title . "</strong></p>";

        printf("<p>This is a password protected entry. If you have a password, log in below.</p>");

        printf("<form method=\"post\" action=\"post.php?id=%s\"><p><strong><label for=\"username\">Username:</label></strong><br /><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" id=\"username\" /></p><p><strong><label for=\"pass\">Password:</label></strong><br /><input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\" id=\"pass\" /></p><p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" /></p></form>",$id);
        print "<hr />";
    }
    else { ?>

        <p><strong><?php echo $title; ?></strong><br /><br />
        <?php echo $entry; ?><br /><br />
        Posted on <?php echo $date; ?>

        <hr /></p>

        <?php
    }
} 
   ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you add one tab/4 spaces in front of the code before posting it to enable formatting.

Comment: Your code uses echo, printf and print... pick one and use it and it's probably not printf().  Also use single quotes around your HTML then you won't have to escape all your HTML quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your title with an `a` tag and append the post ID (or some other unique field) to the link, something like:

```
echo "<p><strong><a href=\"?id=". $id . "\">" . $title . "</a></strong></p>";
```

You can then detect if someone is looking for a specific blog post by looking for the id parameter in the querystring:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    // display blog entry
} else {
    // display your blog's front page
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris. I really appreciate it. The post titles finally link to their corresponding posts!